# PHP generate JSON code

Tags: php, mysql, json, select

Model JSON: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/vjq9j5gwkbrly3y/data.json

How can I generate the above JSON using PHP, including the separate categories in to the above model?

I need help to separate the above categories for JSON. Do I have to do several selects?

Comment: Not sure what you mean by do i have to do several selects....as you're not mentioning MYSQL at all , youre asking how to generate JSON with php

Answer (score 2):

Just build your arrays,

```
    $array = array("Restaurants"=>array(
      array("ID"=>23,"name"=>"test","example"=>"ex"),
      array("ID"=>23,"name"=>"test","example"=>"ex"),
      array("ID"=>23,"name"=>"test","example"=>"ex")
     ),
    "Categories"=>array(
      array("cat"=>"example","ex"=>"example"),
      array("cat"=>"example","ex"=>"example")
     )
     );
```

Then use json_encode

```
    echo json_encode($array);
```

[EXAMPLE](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/439e44e0141db7f67cb422178182df1690969208)